# Animation only occurs once on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Image animates only once, when we scroll and scroll down again the animation doesn't happen again. Any suggestions why this is happening?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
      $('.screen-phone').css('position', 'fixed').animate({
        right: "0px",
      }, "15s");
    } else {
      $('.screen-phone').css('position', 'relative');
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="tel:000000">
  <img src="https://www.abc.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Call-us.svg" class="screen-phone" />
</a>
```

Comment: Please take care to format your questions so they are readable. I've done it for you in this instance. To answer the question, it's because you don't reset the `right` position when the user scrolls back up to the top of the page.

Comment: image is not render

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you of the help! how do i reset the position when user scrolls back up to the page?

Comment: Use `css()` like you do for the `position`